# Parsing C Style Multiline Comment

Tags: bash, shell-script, sed, grep, regular-expression

I want to filter non-commented javascript with `sed` and output the line number

Here is the example:

```
/*!
* jQuery UI 1.8.17
*
* Copyright 2011, AUTHORS.txt (http://jqueryui.com/about)
* Dual licensed under the MIT or GPL Version 2 licenses.
* http://jquery.org/license
*
* http://docs.jquery.com/UI
*/(function(a,b){function d(b)       {return!a(b).parents().andSelf().filter(f/*!
* jQuery UI Widget 1.8.17
*
* Copyright 2011, AUTHORS.txt (http://jqueryui.com/about)
* Dual licensed under the MIT or GPL Version 2 licenses.
* http://jquery.org/license
*
* http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Widget
*/(function(a,b){if(a.cleanData){var  c=a.cleanData;a.cleanData=function(b/*!
* jQuery UI Mouse 1.8.17
*
* Copyright 2011, AUTHORS.txt (http://jqueryui.com/about)
* Dual licensed under the MIT or GPL Version 2 licenses.
* http://jquery.org/license
*
* http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Mouse
*
* Depends:
*   jquery.ui.widget.js
*/
```

Somebody told me to use `grep -n` and `sed` regex like this:

```
grep -n "" test.js | sed ':a;$!N;$!ba;s/\/\*[^*]*\*\([^/*][^*]*\*\|\*\)*\///g'
```

It give me output:

```
1:(function(a,b){function d(b){return!a(b).parents().andSelf().filter(f(function(a,b){if(a.cleanData){var c=a.cleanData;a.cleanData=function(b
```

But I want output:

```
9: (function(a,b){function d(b){return!a(b).parents().andSelf().filter(f
17: (function(a,b){if(a.cleanData){var c=a.cleanData;a.cleanData=function(b
```

Is there something wrong with the regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside comments (/* .*? */) remove everything except newlines; grep non empty lines:

```
perl -p0E 's!(/\*.*?\*/)!$1 =~ s/.//gr!egs;' test.js |grep -nP '\S'
```

which outputs:

```
9:(function(a,b){function d(b)       {return!a(b).parents().andSelf().filter(f
17:(function(a,b){if(a.cleanData){var  c=a.cleanData;a.cleanData=function(b
```

Comment: I am happy it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Using Awk:

```
awk '/^*\/\(/ {gsub(/\*\/|\/\*!/,""); print NR":",$0}' js
9: (function(a,b){function d(b)       {return!a(b).parents().andSelf().filter(f
17: (function(a,b){if(a.cleanData){var  c=a.cleanData;a.cleanData=function(b
```